# Raspbian Stretch Lite Install using remote desktop from MAC

Tags: raspbian, vnc, headless

I have to install Raspbian Stretch Lite but I don't have a monitor, only a MacBook Pro, so do you guys think I can connect Raspberry Pi to my laptop and do the installation?

Would I be able to use remote desktop or VNC right from my Mac in order to install Raspbian Stretch?

Answer (score 1):

Check out "Headless Installation"

==== Get Raspbian (or lite)
— Download Raspbian (Raspbian Lite)
    http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

=== get SD card formatter:  https://etcher.io
- install it

=== put Raspbian-lite on the (micro) SD card

Use Etcher to Flash the image onto card

=== Mount the card to mac (to configure headless configuration)
- Pull card out, reinsert so it is mounted for next steps

=== Enable SSH
- create file called "ssh" (or ssh.txt) in the Boot partition

=== Setup WiFi Headless

- create the file wpa_supplicant.conf in the boot partition 
  (quote chars must be straight up/down, traditional, not slanted/matched Unicode chars

country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="your_ssid"
    psk="your_pw"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}

Eject the card,  boot with card in the RPi3

use arp -a on mac to see what IP the pi got or check your router config

ssh to the pi.